# Redirect uri in microsoft azure

Tags: azure, uri

Is there any way to provide query string in microsoft azure registered project.
azure link -
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Overview

when I try to add query strings in redirect uri it is giving error.

redirect uri- http://localhost:8000/contacts/invite?provider=live

error-Failed to update project application. Error detail: URL may not contain a query string. [3Mfpt]

Comment: http://localhost:8000/contacts/invite?provider=live

Comment: I have to add a query string provider=live in above url

Comment: this is giving error.But it works when I use google provider.Azure is giving error for having query string in uri.  How to fix this

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I get it now.